# What am I missing to create a Lens using ImmerJS and Svelte immutable stores

Tags: typescript, svelte-3, immer.js, svelte-store

I'm getting into Svelte and ImmerJS.

Immerjs and Svelte stores **should** be able to compose in a very elegant way.

I have attempted to create a derived writable store from a parent store just using a selector expression where a selector expression (a term borrowed from .NET) is a function lambda that describes how to access some sub part of an object tree.

```
root => root.a.b[10].foo
```

Normally one would have to parse this but I think immerjs has done the hard work already with the proxies and `Draft<T>` class.

So the intention is to be able to do the below.

```
import {writable} from "svelte/store"
import {lens} from "my_magic_lens_library_not_yet_written"

interface Foo {
  a: number
  b: string
}

interface Bar {
  foo1: Foo
  foo2: Foo
}

let bar:Bar = {
  foo1: {a:10, b:"monkey"},
  foo2: {a:20 , b:"cat"}
}

let barStore:Writable<Bar> = writable(bar)

let foo1_a_Store:Writable<number> = lens(barStore, (b:Draft<Bar>) => b.foo1.a)

barStore.subscribe(v=>console.log(v))

foo1_a_Store.set(77)
```

I would hope the output to be

```
{ foo1: { a: 10, b: 'monkey' }, foo2: { a: 20, b: 'cat' } }
{ foo1: { a: 77, b: 'monkey' }, foo2: { a: 20, b: 'cat' } }
```

but it is

```
{ foo1: { a: 10, b: 'monkey' }, foo2: { a: 20, b: 'cat' } }
{ foo1: { a: 10, b: 'monkey' }, foo2: { a: 20, b: 'cat' } }
```

The implementation for the lens is

```
import {writable,Writable} from "svelte/store"
import {produce,Draft} from "immer"


type Updater<T> = (arg0:T)=>T

type Selector<T,U> = ((ar:T)=>U) & ((ar:Draft<T>)=>Draft<U>);

function lens<T,U>(store:Writable<T>, selector:Selector<T,U>):Writable<U>  
{

  let {subscribe, set, update} = store

  function subSet(v:U):void
  {
    let rootUpdater =  (oldValue:T) => {
      return produce(
        oldValue,  
        (ds:Draft<T>) => {  
          let subDraft:Draft<U> = selector(ds)
          Object.assign(subDraft , v)
        }
      )
    }
    update(rootUpdater)
  }

  function subUpdate(updater:Updater<U>):void
  {
    let rootUpdater =  (oldValue:T) => {
      return produce(
          oldValue,  
          (ds:Draft<T>) => {  
            let subDraft:Draft<U> = selector(ds)
            Object.assign(subDraft , updater(selector(oldValue)))  
          }
      )
    }
    update(rootUpdater) 
  }

  return {
      subscribe: subscriber => subscribe(v=>subscriber(selector(v))),
      set: subSet,
      update: subUpdate
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the line that is failing is

```
Object.assign(subDraft , updater(selector(oldValue)))
```

where I try to spread the updated value into the sub draft. Who knows if this is even possible? But it should be. Can somebody figure out the magic sauce to get this working?

There is a live version at repl.it

https://repl.it/@BradPhelan/Substore

Answer (score 0):

Use a new package called [immer-loves-svelte](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer-loves-svelte) I wrote to achieve this. A single function called `subStore` is exported that allows you to create a child store from a parent

```
import {writable,Writable} from "svelte/store"
import {produce,Draft, isDraft} from "immer"
import {subStore} from "immer-loves-svelte"

interface Foo {
  a: number
  b: string
}

interface Bar {
  foo1: Foo
  foo2: Foo
}

let bar:Bar = {
  foo1: {a:10, b:"monkey"},
  foo2: {a:20 , b:"cat"}
}

let barStore:Writable<Bar> = writable(bar)

// magic happens at this line with subStore call
let foo1_a_Store:Writable<number> = 
   subStore(barStore, b => b.foo1.a)

barStore.subscribe(v=>console.log(v))

foo1_a_Store.set(77
```